# R: plot_ly bubble size range seems to be different for each data series

Tags: r, bubble-chart

I did a bubble chart where the color is a categorical data (3 series) and the 3 axes are numerical data, as well as the bubble size.

VAR4 is the size variable of this plot. One of my series (Model3) has only one point (where VAR4 = 0), the second one (Model2) has the same value in all points of the size variable (VAR4 = 0) and, the last one (Model1) has different values for VAR4 (from 0 to 1.0).

That's my command:

```
plot_ly(dfPlotTemp, x=~VAR1, y=~VAR2, z=~VAR3, 
        type='scatter3d', sizes = c(6,12) ,  mode='markers', 
        size=~VAR4, color=~Model,  
        marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter')) %>%
layout(title = 'Final solutions')
```

I attached an image to better explain what is happening.

[image]

What I would like to see: One purple point (Model3), some orange points (Model2) with the same size of the purple one, and some green point (Model1) with different sizes, where the smaller green bubbles are the same size as orange bubbles (because the minimum value for VAR4 is 0 and this is the value of all points in Model 2 and Model3).

Looking at the picture, the bubble size of Model2 (orange) and Model3 (purple) seems to be the same. However, Model1 has smaller bubble points than Model2 and Model3 and this situation couldn't happen since Model2 and Model3 VAR4 = 0 and Model1 VAR4 has values from 0 to 1.0 (I've checked).

I did some search on internet and I've found that this issue happens when you are not defining `sizemode = diameter`, but I did and it is still not working (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1133).
I've already tried to delete/change the `sizes` parameter and to use `sizeref` as well, but neither worked also.

As requested, below is found the result of dput(dfPlotTemp). This dataset was readen from a csv file and "Cenario" was converted as factor because, despite being made of numbers, it is not a numerical variable.

```
structure(list(Cenario = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2327", class = "factor"), 
    Model = c("Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", 
    "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model2", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", 
    "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model1", "Model3"), VAR1 = c(2.9252, 
    2.9252, 0, 1.992, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9582, 1.421, 0, 1.421, 0, 
    1.7302, 0, 0.1509, 0, 0, 3.4013, 1.992, 1.992, 0.0067, 0, 
    0.1072, 0, 1.2911, 1.992, 0, 1.5388, 3.7707, 3.7707, 0, 1.2911, 
    0, 0, 3.5704, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9582, 3.4025, 0, 2.9252, 3.4002, 
    0, 0.0668, 0, 1.992, 0, 1.992, 2.9252, 0, 2.9252, 0, 0, 2.9037, 
    1.992, 0, 0, 3.777, 3.2819, 1.5374, 1.3731, 0, 2.7602, 1.992, 
    0, 2.9037, 0.954, 0.5146, 0, 1.992, 2.3874, 2.6814, 2.3825, 
    0, 0, 2.6814, 0, 2.9252, 2.9252, 2.9252, 0, 1.992, 1.992, 
    2.452, 2.9252, 0, 1.992, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2344, 0, 0, 1.2911, 
    0, 0, 1.2911, 0, 0.9582, 0, 0, 0, 0.3579, 0, 0, 0.6779, 0.1509, 
    1.827, 2.7602, 0, 0, 0, 1.992, 1.2911, 1.2911, 0.1509, 0, 
    1.992, 3.4002, 0, 2.7755, 2.6814, 0, 1.6551, 1.992, 0, 0, 
    2.9037, 2.9252, 0, 2.9252, 2.1804, 1.992, 0, 1.8789, 1.101, 
    0, 0, 3.7793, 2.7816, 2.9252, 2.9252, 0, 2.9252, 2.8739, 
    0, 1.2911, 0, 0, 1.992, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.8375, 1.9669, 1.4506, 
    2.572, 0.6051, 1.992, 2.9252, 0.5146, 0, 2.9252, 2.9252, 
    1.992, 1.8646, 3.1557, 0, 1.992, 0, 1.992, 0, 2.9037, 2.9252, 
    0, 1.992, 1.992, 0.8455, 0, 0.8455, 0, 0.8455, 2.8375, 0.8455, 
    0.8455, 0.521, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.29, 0, 0, 1.99, 2.46, 0, 2.9, 
    0, 0, 2.61, 3.08, 1.45, 0.846, 2.73, 0, 3.7, 2.22, 3.77, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.846, 2.17, 3.23, 0, 0.846, 0.846, 1.21, 2.76, 
    0, 0.151, 3.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.12, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 1.29, 0, 0, 
    0.2, 0.846, 2.93, 3.4, 0, 2.93, 2.3, 2.68, 3.03, 0, 0.151, 
    0, 2.33, 3.62, 0, 2.74, 0, 3.4, 0, 0, 0.151, 0, 1.29, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2.68, 3.05, 2.68, 3.62, 0, 0, 3.07, 0, 3.57, 0, 
    0, 2.93, 1.99, 0, 2.78, 1.11, 2.78, 0, 3.65, 3.32, 2.3, 3.28, 
    0, 0.846, 0, 0, 0.151, 1.52, 1.7, 0.316, 2.76, 2.68, 0, 2.68, 
    0, 0, 0, 1.21, 3.53, 2.04, 1.82, 2.12, 0, 2.97, 2.03, 0, 
    0, 2.68, 0.312, 2.93, 0, 2.96, 3.78, 1.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.17, 
    1.91, 3.23, 0, 2.68, 3.31, 1.37, 2.68, 3.16, 0, 0, 0, 2.67, 
    2.34, 1.21, 0.958, 2.68, 0, 2.68, 2.68, 0, 0, 0, 0.546, 1.36, 
    1.39, 3.48, 0, 3.33, 0, 2.93, 0, 1.99, 2.93, 0, 3.7, 0, 1.99, 
    3.7, 1.99, 1.29, 0, 0, 0, 0), VAR2 = c(25.002, 9.003, 26.003, 
    3.002, 32.004, 2.002, 40.002, 13.002, 0.001, 7.003, 9.002, 
    8.003, 10.002, 8.001, 38.003, 8.001, 19.003, 9.002, 26.002, 
    12.002, 22.002, 33.003, 21.003, 8.001, 31.002, 8.001, 23.002, 
    32.003, 19.003, 12.002, 16.003, 36.003, 8.001, 1.002, 11.002, 
    24.002, 27.003, 42.004, 38.003, 0.001, 13.002, 0.001, 0.001, 
    15.002, 12.002, 3.003, 26.002, 8.002, 0.001, 12.002, 24.002, 
    3.002, 12.002, 24.002, 25.002, 27.002, 30.003, 25.002, 12.002, 
    15.002, 29.002, 28.002, 19.002, 108.003, 12.003, 14.002, 
    8.002, 7.003, 13.003, 15.002, 8.003, 14.002, 17.002, 3.002, 
    34.002, 22.002, 23.002, 26.002, 23.002, 25.003, 15.002, 11.003, 
    6.002, 2.002, 5.002, 12.002, 6.003, 18.003, 12.002, 15.002, 
    3.002, 17.002, 13.002, 11.002, 12.002, 8.001, 15.002, 21.003, 
    8.001, 8.001, 15.002, 8.001, 15.002, 0.001, 0.001, 27.002, 
    11.002, 8.001, 30.002, 9.002, 29.003, 9.002, 23.002, 22.002, 
    27.002, 34.003, 6.002, 3.002, 8.001, 11.003, 8.001, 13.003, 
    12.002, 11.002, 18.003, 12.002, 22.002, 26.003, 26.002, 12.002, 
    15.002, 13.003, 25.002, 4.003, 32.004, 21.002, 3.002, 12.002, 
    25.002, 33.003, 36.003, 35.003, 37.003, 31.003, 24.002, 22.002, 
    12.003, 27.002, 15.003, 10.004, 19.003, 11.003, 15.002, 13.003, 
    3.002, 8.002, 0.001, 8.002, 0.001, 12.002, 25.004, 39.004, 
    34.004, 38.004, 3.002, 19.003, 5.002, 22.003, 2.002, 12.002, 
    6.003, 31.003, 31.002, 40.002, 3.002, 15.002, 12.002, 20.003, 
    25.002, 12.002, 30.003, 12.002, 16.003, 10.002, 14.002, 10.002, 
    14.002, 10.003, 12.002, 15.002, 14.002, 51.003, 1.002, 0.001, 
    8.002, 12, 8, 10, 29, 23, 41, 34, 25, 33, 23, 33, 41, 24, 
    17, 13, 39, 14, 13, 12, 2, 11, 0.001, 14, 10, 4, 3, 28, 24, 
    15, 11, 8, 35, 12, 40, 28, 30, 23, 13, 3, 23, 40, 16, 8, 
    30, 26, 10, 6, 12, 2, 6, 4, 35, 30, 22, 47, 8, 9, 24, 14, 
    18, 14, 15, 11, 12, 15, 8, 21, 8, 7, 8, 0.001, 27, 18, 20, 
    12, 22, 17, 21, 8, 16, 24, 36, 50, 4, 5, 24, 12, 4, 3, 17, 
    2, 2, 23, 22, 34, 10, 14, 10, 8, 8, 8, 11, 8, 1, 14, 5, 27, 
    28, 31, 36, 37, 55, 48, 52, 14, 6, 10, 42, 23, 20, 30, 25, 
    35, 22, 21, 29, 47, 30, 16, 14, 4, 9, 3, 14, 4, 0.001, 1, 
    20, 24, 32, 0.001, 31, 28, 10, 29, 0.001, 14, 35, 5, 4, 0.001, 
    9, 13, 8, 29, 28, 23, 31, 34, 34, 25, 15, 3, 12, 13, 3, 15, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 26, 21), VAR3 = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 
    16L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 
    17L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 19L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 
    15L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 13L, 
    15L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 
    15L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 
    12L, 13L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
    12L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 
    16L, 20L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 18L, 17L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 15L, 17L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 
    13L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 
    15L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 
    16L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 21L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 
    16L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 
    15L, 12L, 14L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    15L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 15L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 
    17L, 16L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 13L, 
    16L, 16L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 
    14L, 23L, 13L, 14L, 21L, 14L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 13L, 
    13L, 15L, 13L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 17L, 16L, 
    18L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 
    14L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 
    17L, 16L, 15L, 19L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 16L, 19L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 
    15L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    12L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 
    12L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 
    12L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 14L, 18L, 
    14L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 19L, 18L, 22L, 
    12L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 14L), VAR4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Cenario", "Model", "VAR1", "VAR2", 
"VAR3", "VAR4"), row.names = c(NA, -370L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add the results of `dput(dfPlotTemp)` to the question, to make this reproducible - I suspect that setting `sizes= c(6,12)` is the issue (with these two values getting recycled), but I'd like to test